# Announced a company event: now people are starting to slack off, What should I do?

Tags: management, events

I have a very, very small company. About 90% of the product is ready to go. The launch of the product is slated to go up next month on the company's anniversary that is also my birthday. Now everyone is thinking "oh, well the product is almost done, I'm gonna take a ridiculous amount of time off." I want to figure out how I can encourage people to work without making them afraid of losing their job.

DISCLAIMER: I let them have all holidays off.

Comment: Do you live in a country that celebrates Christmas?

Comment: @Questor yes I do

Comment: Did you factor in the holiday season into your project plans?  It seems reasonable to assume that most of your workforce will take vacation time at the tail end of December.  Also, you presumably approved that vacation time, so who's ultimately to blame here?  Based on your questions in Astronomy, I get the feeling this question is hypothetical in nature.

Comment: What is the vacation policy at your company?

Comment: In the general case, this question doesn't have enough details to answer. In this specific case, the holiday season makes it a moot point. That said, I am curious whether you made your expectation that folks work through the holidays clear when you announced the date of the launch.

Comment: Not sure about your project management folks, but mine take holidays and vacation in to consideration. That is, nothing will get done (and is not scheduled to be done) between December 22 and January 3rd this year. Your fixation on launching on your birthday is your problem.

Comment: @JonCuster  Very true.  Never schedule anything significant for August or December.

Comment: Your disclaimer doesn't address the existing requests for clarification: Did you factor the holiday season into your project plans? (Boots) What is the vacation policy at your company? (sf02) Is this question asking how to enforce an existing policy that folks are violating or are you wanting to ask people to shorten their vacations to deal with a planning mistake? Are your employees aware you didn't expect them to take this time off? (me)

Comment: -1, Disclaimer doesn't add anything and seems to assume that  single day holidays are sufficient.

Regular people don't live to work, they work to live.

Answer (score 10):

I am going to challenge one of the assumptions made in this question.
Based on the season that this question was asked (December) and its proximity to an extremely important holiday (Christmas) coupled with the fact that this is occurring in a place that celebrates Christmas.

**Your employees are not slacking off/taking vacation days because they heard that the project is nearly done**. They are taking vacations because they want to spend time with their families/loved ones, ***the reason why they come to work every day.***

Instead of viewing this as a "them" problem, consider this as an opportunity for you to learn an important part about scheduling. Most of your workforce is going to take a week off (at least) during December. You can take that into account when you make plans, or you can try to get by the other 11 months of the year with less employees (its really hard to find good people right now), the choice is up to you.

*High skilled individuals will find work elsewhere if you try to prevent them from spending Christmas with friends and family.

Edit: For the added disclaimer.

One day off for a holiday is great and all... But I often travel for holidays, and my relatives don't live next door (hence 'travel'). They live a day away. So 2 days to travel there and back, but If I am going to spend time traveling (not fun) its better if I spend more time... So why not spend a week with them? travel on the weekends (Saturday and then the next Sunday) and spend 7 days with them...

But driving makes me really tired, as does vacationing the day after I get home so I take that day off as well... That's 5 PTO + 1 holiday off of work for Christmas and I spend 7 days visiting family, 2 days traveling, and 1 day on a vacation from my vacation.

Which is why It is a safe assumption to make that everyone will try to take at least a week off for Christmas... Maybe more.

Comment: ++++1 - _'High skilled individuals will find work elsewhere if you try to prevent them from spending Christmas with friends and family.'_

Answer (score 3):

First things first:  **do not assume that there is a motive for your employees looking to take time off**.

This mentality in why you think everyone's taking off isn't a good mindset to have, since it paints a very negative picture in your mind of what time off actually represents.

> Now everyone is thinking "oh, well the rocket is almost done, I'm gonna take a ridiculous amount of time off."

It really wouldn't matter if the rocket was halfway done or barely done or not even started - if someone wants to take time off and they have earned that time off, they are (generally) within their rights to do so.

Second, to your general question:

> I want to figure out how I can encourage people to work without making them afraid of losing their job.

People don't tend to *fear* losing their job unless the company isn't performing, or there are missed deadlines, or there's generally a bad vibe coming from leadership.  People tend to start *looking around* if ***any*** of the above conditions are met, though.

Hate to say it, but one such bad vibe to cause me personally to want to jump ship is if leadership is asking me to work a little while more when I've got scheduled time off.  In spite of what the company means to me or how well I've been working with them, a question like that has the impact of leadership just seeing me as a robot who is here to help with their completed product rather than a coworker.

So how do you encourage people to work?  By respecting their time!  If they want to take time off and the company policy allows for this, then *let them*.  If you're hearing directly that people are afraid for their jobs, then *listen to those specific concerns*.  Do your best not to conflate one concern with another.

Comment: +++1 - _'there's generally a bad vibe coming from leadership.'_

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is "how much is 'ridiculous', as in your question"?  As other answers have stated, it is December, which means Christmas, and that's traditionally a time when people take a lot of time off.  It also means winter, which means warm destination vacations, so if you're in a cold locale (mostly Canada or the northern US) that could also be a thing people do.

The best way to lose employees and/or employee motivation is to not allow them to take advantage of the benefits of their contract which they have earned and deserve.  You may consider the dichotomy between "people working" and "people taking vacation".  The true dichotomy is between "people taking vacation" and "people leaving your company".  Given that your project is 90% complete, how would your company do if your entire workforce decided "management won't let me take vacation, that's messed up, I'm going to find a company that isn't messed up", and up and left you high and dry with 10% of the project left to do?  That's the end result of the mindset you have.

But again, this goes back to "how much is 'ridiculous'?".  There's a middle ground here.  If people are taking a week or 2 of vacation, that's what you get for being a business owner in December; people take vacations.  If you have people taking months at a time of vacation (and especially PTO), that might be a red flag that something is going wrong.  You should have policies that cover this sort of thing.  Vacations should be allowed, but they should go through approval processes, and managers (yourself included, as the CEO) are responsible for determining that the work still gets done while people are made able to take vacations, which they, again, have earned and are entitled to.  You should say yes to any reasonable request, but you should say no to an unreasonable one.  This being December, you should be a bit extra lax in terms of what is considered "reasonable".  Things you should have in policy include (but are not limited to) the following:

1. Deadlines should not be missed.  Managers or team leads are responsible for their teams' deadlines; managers (not team members) should be censured if deadlines are missed due to vacations (managers are responsible for approving vacations, so they should be encouraged to deny vacations which would impact deadlines, or, at the very least, negotiate with stakeholders, yourself included, as to what the impact on the deadline would be and if it would be acceptable, and deny the vacation request if it would not).
2. "Unreasonable" durations of vacation should be denied.  What this means depends on you.  I would say the maximum duration of a "reasonable" vacation is 3 weeks.  Exceptions can be made on a case-by-case basis, of course.  This is not to negate any law or statute in your locale that would require you to give more vacation than this, and does not include such "vacations" as parental leave or extended medical leave.
3. An entire team should not all take a vacation at the same time, where at all possible.  The lights need to be still kept on, and deadlines need to still be met.  Exceptions, again, on a case-by-case basis, particularly for the month of December (everyone wants to, and should be able to, celebrate Christmas and/or New Years with family and friends).

And, as a final comment, absolutely, positively, do not assume nefarious action on the part of your employees.  If you think your employees are sabotaging your company, fire them.  Otherwise, you're just engaging in paranoia.  Don't do that; it will drive you crazy (literally) and make nobody want to work for you.